# Why ROLES and POLICIES Exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I understand the difference between roles and policies but the question
is why these two exists?
I mean why not use AWS Services with Policies?
thanks

Comment: *"I mean why not use AWS Services with Policies"*  What does this question mean?  Please clarify.

Comment: That's because policies can be attached to Roles and IAM Users. You can re-use the same policy for a service deployed in AWS (using roles) and in non-AWS environment like datacenter (using IAM Users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM roles are similar to IAM users. We create roles to execute operations on required AWS Service.

> For example: We can create a role that can perform a write operation
>   on DynamoDB table and assign that role to a lambda function. Then the
>   lambda function can use this role's privilege to write something on
>   DynamoDB.

Policies are simply JSON documents in which we can specify permissions: operations can be allowed or denied. Policies are attached to IAM identities such as users, groups and roles.

So the question is why both exists, why not use AWS service with Policies. The simple answer is we actually are using the AWS services with policies but in the name of IAM user or roles.

Answer (score 0):

Policies get assigned to Roles. Roles do nothing on their own. You should use roles for services for simplicity and security. When assigning roles to a service you don't need to provide AWS access keys directly to these services anymore since they will be provided to the environment by the role. This is much more secure and simple then needing to pass these items to a service or application running on AWS and needing to secure them both on the service and in code.